# Composer issue after I deleted the vendor directory

Tags: composer

We have Drupal 8.8.5 running on CentOS Linux 7 with PHP 7.1.33.

Was trying to update modules using composer. Composer said they were updated, but when I went into program, they weren't. In troubleshooting, I deleted the "vendor" directory. Now, I get this error:

> [root@ip-172-31-13-94 master]# composer update --with-dependencies
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.0 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.0-beta1 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.0-rc1 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.1 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.2 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.3 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.4 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.5 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.x-dev requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta1 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta2 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.x-dev requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
>   - Conclusion: don't install composer/installers v1.7.0
>   - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended ^8.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.8.0, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.x-dev, 8.9.0-beta1, 8.9.0-beta2, 8.9.x-dev].

Can someone tell us how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: You deleted the vendor directory, your only recourse here is composer install. Modules aren't installed to vendor either, by the way.

Comment: $ composer install (results in same error)

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue:

$ composer selfupdate

Updating to version 1.10.5 (stable channel).
   Downloading (100%)
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.6.2

Appaprently, my version of composer was too old.